# How can I tweed a Randomly Generated Quote from within wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, quote

I havent been able to find any information on this anywhere online but in my Wordpress site I have a quote thats generated from within a few arrays in PHP...

I'd like to call upon the generated quote and tweet the said quote out along with a link to my website... I'm really new to this (basically can't code at all. I've started going through code academy's PHP course but its not really sticking) so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Anyone offer a hand on how I might do this?

Here's what my Wordpress page-jimmy.php looks like:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    class Jimmy {
        public $a = array(
            array("The world","The mind","Hidden meaning","Good health",),
            array("relies on","depends on","embraces","requires","results from"),
            array("your own","infinite","self-righteous","unbridled","unique","innumerable"),
            array("responsibility","creativity","life","possibilities","observations")
        );
        public $life1 = array("Dogs","Cats","Mice","Rats","Lobsters","Crows");
        public $life2 = array("the savior","the hero","the man","as mules","as birds","givers in the transcendental","something to watch out for!");
        public function getQuote() {
            $rn = rand(0, 100);// slight chance of making an animal based quote
            if ($rn < 2) {
                return $this->life1[array_rand($this->life1)] . " are " . $this->life2[array_rand($this->life2)];
            } else {
                $oa = array();
                if (isset($_SESSION)){// store the variables in the session, reload them if need be
                    $i = 0;
                    foreach ($this->a as $ar){
                        $i++;
                        $is = "s".strval($i);
                        if (!isset($_SESSION[$is])){
                            $_SESSION[$is] = $ar;
                        } elseif(empty($_SESSION[$is])){
                            $_SESSION[$is] = $ar;
                        }
                        shuffle($_SESSION[$is]);
                        $oa[] = array_pop($_SESSION[$is]);
                    }
                } else {
                    foreach ($this->a as $ar) {
                        $oa[] = $ar[array_rand($ar)];
                    }
                }
                return implode(" ", $oa);
            }
        }
    }
    get_header();
?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <?php
    // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            // Include the page content template.
            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'page' );
            $blah = new Jimmy();
            $var = $blah->getQuote();
            echo '<div class="quote anim-typewriter">"'.$var.'"</div>';
            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the 
            comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {comments_template();}
            // End of the loop.
        endwhile;
    ?>
    </main><!-- .site-main -->
    <?php get_sidebar( 'content-bottom' ); ?>
</div><!-- .content-area -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</pre>
```

Thanks...

Comment: Where are you stuck? Is the quote being generated? Do you just need the tweet function?

Comment: The code is being generated now..! So it works... and is showing the generated quotes randomly... but I want to find a way to tweet it the generated quote... a button that includes the quote and a link back to the site. No idea how I might do that...


I was looking at this but im not sure what code i'd add to call upon the quote being put in..

similar to how its being done here... 

"Tweet the Wisdom"

http://www.wisdomofchopra.com/

Comment: You should look into the Twitter API to do this. This link may help you: http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_twitter_with_php